# Cannot create iterator - igraph - R

Tags: r, igraph, random-forest

I am trying to create an isolation forest algorithm using solitude package in R. When I am calling the fit method in R, I am getting the following error.

```
iso <- isolationForest$new()
isofit = iso$fit(data)
```

Error in igraph::distances(treegraph, v = 1L, to = tnValues + 1L, mode = "out") : 
  At iterators.c:759 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id

What am I doing wrong here. I am stuck and I cant train my model. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to increase mtry

```
iso$mtry <- 5 # default value is 1
```

After encountering the same problem and digging around for some time, i think that I found the problem.

deep into the fit function a call is being made to the function  solitude::terminalNodesDepth, which in turn makes this call:

```
future.apply::future_lapply(1:num_trees, function(x) terminalNodesDepthPerTree(ranger::treeInfo(model, x)))
```

The function "terminalNodesDepthPerTree" extracts something from each tree in the trained ranger model, using the ranger::treeInfo.

For some of the trees however, there are no splits: so treeInfo returns:

```
  nodeID leftChild rightChild splitvarID splitvarName splitval terminal prediction
1      0        NA         NA         NA         <NA>       NA     TRUE    1385.02
```

Which results in the error!

I solved the problem by increasing mtry, which defaults to 1.

hope it helps :)